# One Css transition is jumpy while the other works fine

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, transition

The transition on icon-open works fine for me but the transition for wrapper does not work. Wrapper simply jumps from left to right without using the transition. I am using Jquery for the animation. Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5vyLd7nf/ .

```
.icon-open{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.7em;
    left: .4em;
    font-size: 2em;
    z-index: 5;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
.wrapper{
    top:4.1em;
    position: relative;
    width: 80em;
    height: 800em;
    z-index: 2;
    background: beige;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;

}
.open2{
    left: 16.1em;
}

.open3 {
    left: 8.3em
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".icon-open").click(function () {
        $(".wrapper").toggleClass("open2");
        $(".icon-open").toggleClass("open3");
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you have you code in fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5vyLd7nf/

Comment: Might be worth noting some values animate better than others. Opacity and transforms don't require reflows so have better performance. It is recommended to use translation instead of manipulating position values (top, right, bottom, left) where appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the initial position of `.wrapper` to `0` (see the [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vyLd7nf/4/)):

```
.wrapper {
    left: 0;
    top:4.1em;
    position: relative;
    width: 80em;
    height: 800em;
    z-index: 2;
    background: beige;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
```

According to MDN on `position: relative`:

> This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing layout

`relative` has no initial notion of it's original left or top position unless you set it explicitly.